# Unnotarized Developer ID after successful notarization

Tags: electron, electron-builder, apple-developer, notarize

When I run

```
spctl -vvv --assess --type exec dist/mas/myapp-1.1.9.pkg
```

I get

```
rejected
source=Unnotarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: MyCompany Inc (XXXXXXXXX)
```

So then I run the notarization

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app -f dist/mas/myapp-1.1.9.pkg --primary-bundle-id com.mycompany.myapp -u myemail@domain.com -p my-app-password --asc-provider myprovider
```

As result I got

```
No errors uploading 'dist/mas/myapp-1.1.9.pkg'.
RequestUUID = xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx
```

But when I run again the spctl command, i get

```
rejected
source=Unnotarized Developer ID
```

Comment: Did you inspect the log?  `xcrun notarytool log` uuid

Comment: When I tried that I always get:

xcrun notarytool log XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX --apple-id=myemail@domain.com --password=my-app-password --team-id=teamXXX
Submission log is not yet available or submissionId does not exist
  id: XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: I get an email from apple, when the app has been notarized successfull. Which means that it went well. But I'm strugling with same problem. I'm signing/notarizing an electron app into a .dmg image. Cant get it to start without gatekeeper blocking it...